# NHibernate: Mapping query results to a list property in mapping file

Tags: c#, nhibernate, file, collections, mapping

I have a Contact class and I want to provide the users with AutoComplete for City and Province.

I Thought I create two collections in the Contact object and load the Cities and Provinces from the contact table on them:

```
public class Contact {  
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }  
    public virtual string City { get; set; }  
    public virtual string Province { get; set; }  
    public virtual IList<String> Cities { get; set; }  
    public virtual IList<String> Provinces { get; set; }  
}
```

And have the mapping file like this:

```
<class name="Contact">  
    <id name="Id">  
        <generator class="native">  
            <param name="sequence">contact_id_seq</param>  
        </generator>  
    </id>  
<property name="Name" />  
<property name="City" />  
<property name="Province" />  
<property name="Cities" type="string" formula="SELECT DISTINCT city FROM contact" />  
<property name="Provinces" type="string" formula="SELECT DISTINCT province FROM contact" />  
</class>
```

But this does not work.  Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: please start by reading the basic docs: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula on property is an SQL expression that defines the value for the property, so the select should return a single value. In addition by working in the way you proposed you will duplicate those values on each entity, maybe is better to define it as a static list and fill the value by a custom hql when, for example, a new session is created.

Comment: I was trying to save the trips to the database. Is there a way to load <list> or <map> or <bag> without a relationship?  Just from a view that will run the queries above and load this IList<String> properties?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can map a view as any other table, you can specify mutable=false to enforce the constraint you cant't write in a view.

Comment: I guess the static list is what makes more sense for this purpose.  Thank you for your input.